# java eclipse mars libgdx cannot find main on my desktop project package to run a gamescreen

Tags: java, android, eclipse, youtube, libgdx

hello i'm just a total beginner on programming in general. i was following this guy called EddieVanHallen98 on youtube about how to make a 2-d game. i was alright until this chapter about install libgdx. (it was chapter 21 but this is the 'update version' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6i78aqugqds. after torturing myself to finally install the damn sdk android (and of course libgdx) and making visible my AppData in general i jumped out to see the next chapter https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCwuJy7RRuM (22-screens). now, the class/file/package placement and the initial code of this guy is totally different from mine. here my code:

```
     `package com.loosealpha.project; // this class comes from a file named core or something

    import com.badlogic.gdx.Game; //modified from (errm application-something i forgot) to. Game
    import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

    public class Project extends Game{ 
        SpriteBatch batch;
        Texture img;
        public GameScreen game_screen; // added while watching the tutorial

        @Override
        public void create () {
            batch = new SpriteBatch();
            img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
            game_screen = new GameScreen(this); //added while watching the tutorial
            setScreen(game_screen);// same 
        }

        @Override
        public void render () {
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            batch.begin();
            batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
            batch.end();
    }
}
`
```

the only thing i changed on this code (and probably my mistake) was to change the original name of an imported package (which i can't remeber. really, it was named 'com.badlogic.gdx.(application or something like that)' to   'com.badlogic.gdx.Game;'also added code that the tutorial was asking me to do write. (see // on my code.) i also created this class to make a constructor GameScreen:

```
`package com.loosealpha.project;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;

public class GameScreen implements Screen{

    private Project  game;

    public GameScreen(Project game){
        this.game = game;
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {`
```

now, i just wanted to see a nice little screen black screen window (oh yeah i use windows 10) and the tutorial said to run on the main class of my project desktop file thingy (i don't know is it said it only says the name of my project and desktop on the package explorer) but i didn't find any Main class. just a class named DesktopLauncher.java and i doens't give the results i desire (a black screen window) instead it runs the console and grapple. i hope i just gave enough info, really, i need serious help i don't want to give up

Comment: DesktopLauncher is the main class of a default LibGDX project. It needs to call `initialize(new Project(), config);` Is that missing from yours? Don't worry about the package names. If you had messed that up, it wouldn't even compile.

Comment: i  need to write  'initialize(new Project(), config);' on the desktoplaucher or in the core main?

Comment: Desktop launcher, but but should already be there unless you changed it.

Comment: *sigh* is there a way to reset my project? i didn't advance too much anyways

Comment: Only by creating a new one. And if you're not in love with Eclipse, I would use Intellij instead. Way fewer project setup headaches.

Comment: thanks for all this help, but i may take some steps back and learn more about java

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using IntelliJ over Eclipse for LibGDX development. Just generate the LibGDX project using the GUI tool, and open the Gradle project in Intellij.

To run on Desktop:

1. Click Run -> Edit Configurations and a new window will pop up
2. Click the plus (+) button on the top left and select Application
3. Set the `Name` field to Desktop (or anything else)
4. Set the `Main class` field to DesktopLauncher
5. Set the `Working directory` field to the android/assets/ directory
6. Set the `Use classpath of module` dropdown to the desktop module

Reference:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA

Comment: this instructions are for eclipse, intelliJ or both?